# Issue about utf-8-sig encoding and tab delimiter on csv file

Tags: pandas, csv

I want to save some DataFrame data to csv file with '\t' delimiter, and because there are Chinese characters in data so use `utf-8-sig` encoding. But encountered a issue that Excel can't auto load columns correctly when both `utf-8-sig` encoding and '\t' delimiter.

Firstly, code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': ['a', 'b\tc', '你好', 'test code']})
# case1
df.to_csv('case1.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
# case2
df.to_csv('case2.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
# case3
df.to_csv('case3.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', sep='\t'.encode('utf-8'), index=False)
df.to_csv('case4.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep='\t'.encode('utf-8'), index=False)
```

The result as follows(open case file with excel):

case1.csv:[image]

case2.csv:[image]

case3.csv:[image]

case4.csv:[image]

So how modify the code when both `utf-8-sig` and '\t' delimiter that Excel can auto load columns correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing the extension of the file to ".tsv" instead of ".csv". Also `.encode('utf-8')` is not needed in this case.

Comment: The problem is, that by default Excel does not recognize a tab as a column seperator. Depending on the language by default it is comma or a semicolon.
You can open the file with an editor like Notepad++ to see the raw data.

Comment: @QusaiAlothman I try ".tsv" can't worked.

Comment: @EyJay What did you mean "Depending on the language by default it is comma or a semicolon." And when I try `df.to_csv('case4.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep='\t'.encode('utf-8'), index=False)`, excel open case4.csv correctly. The picture as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that by default Excel does not recognize a tab as a column seperator when using encoding `utf-8-sig` like @EyJay said, this may be Excel's limit.
Finally, I solve this problem by using encoding `utf-16`.[reference](https://superuser.com/questions/956200/utf-8-file-is-not-showing-chinese-characters-in-excel)

```
    df.to_csv('case5.csv', encoding='utf-16', sep='\t'.encode('utf-8'), index=False)
```

Answer (score -2):

df.to_csv('case4.csv', sep='\t', index=False,encoding='gbk')